# При попытке записать данные в БД, laravel выдаёт ошибку Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Только начал изучать laravel и у меня была подобная ошибка где не выполнялась миграция, это решилось тем, что я раскоментировал строку в php.ini . Теперь я опять столкнулся с этой же проблемой. После заполнения всех данных в форме и нажатии кнопки с submit , пишет:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: insert into `users_models` (`login`, `password`) values (Vitaliy, 12121212121))
```

Версия php в OpenServer 8.0 , установлена тоже версия 8.0. Вот код:

```php
       public function regUser(Request $request){
            $validData = $request->validate([
                'login' => 'required|min:4|max:20',
                'password' => 'required|min:4|max:20'
            ]);
    
    
            $user = new UsersModel();
            $user->login = $request->input('login');
            $user->password = $request->input('password');
    
            $user->save();
    
            return redirect(route('/'));
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё ошибку исправил. Сам проект в OpenServer был открыт через под папку папку и даже сайт не мог открыть.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).